# Kaminari params on first page config option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, kaminari

I am trying to set this option to true as described in the documentation. I used `rails g kaminari:config` which generated the following kaminari_config.rb :

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  # config.default_per_page = 25
  # config.max_per_page = nil
  # config.window = 4
  # config.outer_window = 0
  # config.left = 0
  # config.right = 0
  # config.page_method_name = :page
  # config.param_name = :page
end
```

The params_on_first_page option not being present, I tried to add it before the end, this way : `config.params_on_first_page = true`

However, this doesn't seem to work, and I can't launch my rails server anymore. It gives me the following error :

```
Exiting
/home/vincent/workspace/bam-rails/config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb:10:in block in <top (required)>': undefined methodparam_on_first_page=' for #Kaminari::Configuration:0x0055c09deaddb0 (NoMethodError)
Did you mean? param_name=
```

I am using the version 0.17.0 of Kaminari. Am I missing something ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here : https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/831

I missed to add `github: "amatsuda/kaminari"` in my Gemfile, whereas the option was only available on branch master.